# Wordpress if/elseif

Tags: php, wordpress

I can't seem to get this condensed properly to use if and elseif instead of two separate if statements. I have the following:

```
if (is_page('series-1000')) {

$query = new WP_Query( array( 'page_id' => '6' ) );



if ( $query->have_posts() ) :

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 

          get_template_part ('series'); 

     endwhile; 

endif; 
 } 

if (is_page('series-4000-5000')) {

$query = new WP_Query( array( 'page_id' => '5' ) );



if ( $query->have_posts() ) :

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 

    get_template_part ('series');

    endwhile;

endif;
}
```

I am not sure how to end one section and start the next.

Comment: If you'd remove all of the PHP opening and closing tags it would make it much easier to read and to fix.

Comment: Also, you should probably pick either brackets or endifs and stick with it.

Comment: I have removed them Jay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
if (is_page('series-1000')) {
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'page_id' => '6' ) );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) { 
            $query->the_post(); 
            get_template_part ('series'); 
        } 
    } 
} else if (is_page('series-4000-5000')) {
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'page_id' => '5' ) );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) { 
            $query->the_post(); 
            get_template_part ('series');
        }
    }
}
```